# Finding tuples of numbers subject to constraints

Tags: python, combinatorics

I just watched the video from ["Think Like a Programmer, Episode 2: Puzzles & Problems"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2bkfA2fHVwg).

The problem is:

> Assign number 1-7 to three departments in a city: Fire, Police,
>   Sanitation.
>
> Requirement:
>
> - Each department should have a unique number
> - Police should be an even number
> - Fire + Police + Sanitation = 12
>
> Generate a list of permutations for these department numbers.

Here is my Python attempt:

```
def valid_department_number(f, p, s):
    if (f != p != s) and (f+p+s == 12) and p % 2 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

numbers = range(1, 8)

for f in numbers:
    for p in numbers:
        for s in numbers:
            if valid_department_number(f, p, s):
                print(f, p, s)
```

I searched the python documentation and found that I could use the `permutations` function from `itertools`:

```
import itertools


all_permutations = list(itertools.permutations(numbers, 3))

for each_p in all_permutations:
    f, p, s = each_p[0], each_p[1], each_p[2]
    if valid_department_number(f, p, s):
        print(each_p)
```

The `permutation` function gets rid of three levels of nested `for` loops. I'm wondering whether there's a better way to deconstruct the tuples from `permutation` generated list of tuples.

Comment: As we all want to make our code more efficient or improve it in one way or another, try to write a title that summarizes what your code does, not what you want to get out of a review. For examples of good titles, check out [Best of Code Review 2014 - Best Question Title Category](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/3883/23788) You may also want to read [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/2438/41243).

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan Thank you very much for the reference link - I'm new here, the links are great for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the contracts of [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) is:

> So if the input elements are unique, there will be no repeat values in each permutation.

So the full-blown solution with `permutations` doesn't need to check for equality at all (thereby avoiding the trap of writing `x != y != z` to test for mutual inequality):

```
def valid_assignments():
    for f, p, s in itertools.permutations(range(1, 8), 3):
        if f+p+s == 12 and p%2 == 0:
            yield f, p, s
```

However, this is less efficient than necessary simply because there are 210 things you're iterating over. It'd be better to iterate over just `f` and `p` and select `s` as a result:

```
def valid_assignments2():
    for f in xrange(1, 8):          ## f can be any number
        for p in xrange(2, 8, 2):   ## p must be even
            s = 12 - (f+p)
            if 1 <= s <= 7 and f != s and f != p and s != p:
                yield f, p, s
```

Now we're only going over 21 things. Just saved ourselves a bunch of work!

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that the elements are unique in `itertools.permutations`. Though your second solution is more efficient, I like your first one, it is straight forward, clean and easy to maintain.

Answer (score 2):

**`f != p != s` does not prevent `f` and `s` from being equal**

You can improve your algorithmic approach, using your constraints:

```
def iter_permutations():
    total = 12
    for f in range(1, 8):        # Fire must be between 1 and 7
        for p in range(2, 8, 2): # Police must be even
            s = total - p - f    # The sum must be 12
            if 0 < s < 8 and f != p != s != f: # They must be all different
                 yield f, p, s   # Use an iterator, because it's elegant!
```

You can simply use it with : `for f, p, s in iter_permutations():`

I think using an iterator is nicer than a list (you can easily get a list with `list(iter_permutations())` if needed)

Comment: After reading your answer, I tested `f != p != s` and found that you are right. Then in order to express the inequality, I have to write `f != p and p != s and f != s`. Is there a better way to express this?

Comment: @Nick: It would be harder to read but `f != p != s != f` would be a shorter way of testing that none are equal.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan: that's what I implemented in my answer ;-). You can do it more generic: [`if len(x) == len(set(x)):`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5278151/3207406)

Comment: @Nick or you can check if the product is a prime number ^^

Comment: I missed that somehow, oops!

Comment: You also need to check that `s` is in range (i.e. positive).

Comment: @200_success: nice catch! I fixed it

Comment: `s` must not be too large, either.

Comment: @200_success that's (also) right!

Answer (score 0):

Well the short answer is yes there is a better way to unpack the tuple:

```
f, p, s = each_p
```

This unpacks `each_p` into three values so you no longer need to index the three values.

Also there's no need to call `list` on the result of `permutations`. You can iterate over the result with a loop just fine, and it will be more efficient than building a full list of all the permutations up front.

---

Also for `valid_department_number`, instead of using `if` blocks you could return the result of your boolean:

```
def valid_department_number(f, p, s):
    return f != p != s and f + p + s == 12 and p % 2 == 0
```

You don't need the brackets around the separate conditions so I removed them.